# Wait for element to be stable in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, automated-tests

Is there a way to wait for an element to be stable in protractor.

An Element is considered stable when it has maintained the same bounding box for at least two consecutive animation frames.

The reason why I'm searching for this is because in the web app that I'm testing, there a re webcomponents that have animation so it's not possible to click on them unless the animation has ended.

Comment: Can u please add some code?

Comment: @StPaulis There's no code to add here.
I'm actually asking is there's a way to do it.
For example, when a page is loading, an element is changing its position eachtime:
At t0: (x=10,y=10)
At t1: (x=40,y=20)
At t2: (x=70,y=120)

I'm asking if there's a way to wait untill this element reaches its final position, that way I can click on it

Comment: You can either use a retry policy in your function (that should be the easiest way) (You can use Rxjs `interval` for this purpose and you can create a pipeline using `takeUntil`) or  use a `Subject` inside a service that will inform you when your page is ready.

Comment: @StPaulis Would you mind giving me an example ?

Comment: Something like that https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5xb7gh?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts. Although @Sergey's answer might fit better on you.

Answer (score 1):

from your example, it can be solved by waiting until loading animation goes away. eg

```
const {ExpectedConditions} = require('protractor');

await browser.wait(
  ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(this.$loadAnimationHomePage),
  10000,
  'error message'
);
```

---

P.S. or you can write a function to wait until the element has the same coordinates (not move around the page) for at least 1 second, or any other time

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a way to check for the element's stability by doing the following:

````js
/** 
     * Waits for the element to be stable
     * An Element is considered stable when it has maintained the same bounding box for at least two consecutive animation frames.
     */
    async isStable() {
        await browser.wait(
            this.compareElementPositions()
            , this._elapsedTime,
            `Element ${this._locator} is not stable after ${this._elapsedTime} ms`);
    }

    /** 
     * Helper function to isStable()
     * Compares the positions of an element at two different times and returns true once the two positions match each other.
     */
    async compareElementPositions() {
        let pos1 = await this.webElement.getLocation();
        await browser.sleep(200);
        let pos2 = await this.webElement.getLocation();
        return await pos1 === pos2;
    }```

I hope this helps anyone who'll run across the same issue in the future.
````